# Passing value to other page by clicking a list item

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new at web programming and JavaScript.

I have a model page that show all the details of a request let 's say. And Before that page, what the user sees is a list with all the requests he have made. The this is, I want somehow to passe the ID of that clicked request, save it somewhere and pass to the other page and in there, by ID e shows all the details of that previously clicked request.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="list-group">

    <?php

    $id_utilizador = $_SESSION["id_utilizador"];

    if(isset($_POST["por_aprovar"])){

        $url = "http://localhost/myslim_aluguer_viaturas/api/requisicoes/fase1/" . $id_utilizador;

        $json = file_get_contents($url);
        $obj = json_decode($json);
        if($obj->status == true){
            $array = $obj->data;
            foreach($array as $requisicao){                 
                echo "<a href='requisicao.php' name = 'requisicao" . $requisicao->requisicao->id . "' class='list-group-item'>" . $requisicao->nome_condutor . "    |   " . $requisicao->requisicao->deslocacao . "    |    " . $requisicao->descricao_viatura . "     |    " . $requisicao->requisicao->data_requisicao . "</a>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Não existem resultados a apresentar.";
        }
    ?>
```

I don 't know what to do. thank you for your time!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a url query string aka get parameters. In your code change this:

```
echo "<a href='requisicao.php' name = 'requisicao" . $requisicao->requisicao->id . "' class='list-group-item'>" . $requisicao->nome_condutor . "    |   " . $requisicao->requisicao->deslocacao . "    |    " . $requisicao->descricao_viatura . "     |    " . $requisicao->requisicao->data_requisicao . "</a>";
```

To this:

```
echo "<a href='requisicao.php?theid=" . $requisicao->requisicao->id . "' class='list-group-item'>" . $requisicao->nome_condutor . "    |   " . $requisicao->requisicao->deslocacao . "    |    " . $requisicao->descricao_viatura . "     |    " . $requisicao->requisicao->data_requisicao . "</a>";
```

And on `requisicao.php` you will obtain the value using php's super global variable `$_GET[]` which will be something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['theid']) && $_GET['theid'] != ''){

    $the_id = $_GET['theid'];

    // do stuff with $the_id;

}
```

You can pass multiple values by adding additional parameters:

```
requisicao.php?theid=22&anothervar=something&var3=33
```

Also keep in mind the security implications when passing variables via query string parameters as users will be able to easily manipulate these variables, and they will be saved in access logs. Your application should have the logic to sanitize and insure that the values passed are valid.

Comment: Thank you so much it works!! I just want to understand,  after requisicao.php? the "theid" get's this ID by what?

Comment: "theid" is only a variable name that can be changed to anything you would like. The value after the equal sign is the value assigned to that variable name (in this case the value is being concatenated to the string). Any additional variables can be added by appending an ampersand& and following the same pattern "?var1=something&var2=somethingelse&var3=33"

Comment: If this resolved your issue please upvote and accept